# same machine same program different cpu time. Why?

Tags: c, multithreading

I have in my C program a thread doing some works. And I run this thread multiple times in my program with **pthread_create()** in a for-loop as below.

```
for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, thread_run, result_thread[i]);
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
}
```

I'm also keeping track of the cpu time of these threads with **pthread_getcpuclockid()**. The thing is even with the same input the cpu time of these threads can be very different.

For example see below a group of cpu time I've recorded (in milliseconds).

0.0051
   0.0127
   0.0113
   0.0106
   0.0117
   0.0125
   0.0120
   0.0112
   0.0111
   0.0193
   0.0112
   0.0162
   0.0036
   0.0036
   0.0035
   0.0036
   0.0035
   0.0036
   0.0036
   0.0036

What could be the reason of these differences?

I'm using Ubuntu btw.

Comment: That depends on so many things! Like what the processor has to do which other program's he has to handle and so on.

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same, when the state of the computer is different each and every time?

Comment: @Rizier123 Hmm, I'm measuring the CPU time of each thread. What does it have to do with other programs?

Comment: @ScottHunter You're right. I don't expect them to be completely the same. But the differences are bigger than I expected. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Zlol It's not really _very different_, the [standard deviation](http://www.calculator.net/standard-deviation-calculator.html?numberinputs=0.0051%2C0.0127%2C0.0113%2C0.0106%2C0.0117%2C0.0125%2C0.0120%2C0.0112%2C0.0111%2C0.0193%2C0.0112%2C0.0162%2C0.0036%2C0.0036%2C0.0035%2C0.0036%2C0.0035%2C0.0036%2C0.0036%2C0.0036&x=37&y=18) is very small.

Comment: @BSH Yes. but if you look at (standard deviation / mean). It's not that small.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of variables here, it depends what your thread code does and even how your kernel is built. If your thread is making any system calls (it probably is), then you are asking your kernel to do something for you, so it isn't even always your code that is running. If you have a preemptible kernel, then your kernel might decide at some point to stop executing your thread and go do something else. There might even be some memory swapping going on, in which case you would see large differences in performance.
In short, it's your kernel's fault, but it's just doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, it could be the kernel. Would it be better then if I measure only user time, instead of CPU time?